# What does it mean to have a degenerate $S$-matrix?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, s-matrix-theory, unitarity

The [Coleman-Mandula theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coleman%E2%80%93Mandula_theorem) $D>2$ assumes that the quantum field theory may not have a degenerate $S$-matrix. But what does it mean to have a degenerate $S$-matrix?

The $S$-matrix if I got it right connects the initial and final states in an interaction. Does non-degenerate mean singular in the matrix sense, and thus that the interaction would be non-reversible?

Comment: A degenerate matrix need not have an inverse. I can't recall if the inverse of the S matrix is used in the theorem, however.

Answer (score 1):

I guess we can assume that for any "physical" theory, the S-matrix must be invertible. We like to think of the S-matrix as being unitary i.e. $S^\dagger \cong S^{-1}$. For any matrix, so long as the eigenvalues are non-zero, there is a way to normalize the states such the eigenvalues become unimodular. But if there were zero-eigenvalues, then the matrix would not be unitary/invertible. So requiring the S-matrix to be "non-degenerate" is unitarity at the heart of quantum mechanics.